# What is the grammartical function of the prepositional phrase in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, object-complements

> It is likely that the person who led you ***through the zoo*** helped you to
>   learn a lot.

I wonder what is the grammatical function of the prepositional phrase in the above sentence?

In my opinion, the phrase modifies the verb "led", so it works as an adverb. But someone told me that I could add a verb "to be" between the pronoun, you, and the phrase and it makes sense, so the phrase is the complement of the object "you".

I'm a little confused about that.

Comment: I think the basic construction is inherently ambiguous in terms of whether the "adverbial" clause modifies the agent or patient ("subject" or "object"). As Groucho Marx said, [*One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know.*](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/groucho_marx_128462)

Comment: Consider *He's the Peeping Tom who watched me getting undressed*. Same thing. If you want to impose a perverse interpretation, you could visualize the Peeping Tom getting undressed while he watched me cooking dinner, for example.

Comment: I'd say it was a locative complement of "led". It falls under the general heading of 'source, goal and location' complements, where PPs typically hang out.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, *who led you **to be** through the zoo* doesn't make any sense at all. While it's not wrong *syntactically*, somebody being *through the zoo* is mostly nonsensical. A better example (which might work with your question) is *who led you **to run screaming** through the zoo*. Of course, the sentence would be ungrammatical if the *helped you to learn a lot* part of it remained after that. You would do better to provide an actual example of what you have in mind that also makes sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford “who led you through the zoo” is a dependent clause which modifies the antecedent-the person, and it means the person leads "you" in the zoo and give "you" some information. That's what my understanding of the sentence.

Comment: @BillJI think that is what I mean. But in China, we don't have the concept of "verb complement" and we prefer to treat it as an adverbial modifier. I think the structure is SVOA, just like this sentence "I take her out of the room.".

Comment: @HenryWang How does this relate to your question about inserting *to be* into the sentence? Unless you also include the modified version of the sentence, I'm still unclear on what you're asking. (Obviously, my earlier comment had nothing to do with it.)

Comment: @HenryWang No, it's not SVOA, it's SVOC. The same is true of "I take her out of the room", where again the PP is a complement. Expressions of goal and location like this are complements, bot adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJThank you for your explanation. I got it.